# Latex to PDF error unknown float option 'H' Doxygen

Tags: pdf, latex, doxygen, tex, pdflatex

I'm attempting to convert latex to pdf, using doxygen generated latex files. I am using Doxygen 1.8.7. However, I keep getting this error:

```
!LaTex Error: Unknown float option 'H'.
...
1.6 \begin<figure>[H]
```

I've narrowed it down to a .tex file, which contains the following:

```
\hypertarget{group___a_m_s___common}{\section{A\+M\+S\+\_\+\+Common}
\label{group___a_m_s___common}\index{A\+M\+S\+\_\+\+Common@{A\+M\+S\+\_\+\+Common}}
}
Collaboration diagram for A\+M\+S\+\_\+\+Common\+:
 \nopagebreak
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\leavevmode
\includegraphics[width=334pt]{group___a_m_s___common}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\subsection*{Modules}
\begin{DoxyCompactItemize}
\item 
\hyperlink{group___common___error___codes}{A\+M\+S Common Error Codes}
\end{DoxyCompactItemize}


\subsection{Detailed Description}
```

Where do I go from here? Am I right in saying that it's looking for an image that it can't find?

Answer (score 2):

As the latex error says, it's not looping for an image it can't find, but rather encountered an option to a floating element it doesn't understand. The 'H' option for float placement forces a figure to appear exactly at the place it appears in the latex code and essentially not to float. It requires the "[float](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float)" package.

Thus in order to get your code working, add the following to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{float}
```

<strike>I'm not sure how to tell Doxygen that this package is required so as to not have to touch the automatically generated latex files..</strike>
In fact according to the doxygen documentation [here](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_extra_packages) adding the following to your configuration file should do the trick:

```
EXTRA_PACKAGES=float
```

There's a discussion on the 'H' option over [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text) and a rather detailed discussion on latex float placement in general [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat).

Answer (score 2):

This does indeed seem to be an issue with the `float` package. I had the same problem. However, just adding `EXTRA_PACKAGES=float` didn't fix it for me. I finally found [this page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204410/package-fixltx2e-conflicts-with-float-and-cannot-be-resolved-in-lyx) which describes a conflict between the `fixltx2e` package and the `float` package which generates this error about the unknown `H` option. So, I commented out line 11 where it says `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` in the doxygen generated tex file (called `refman.tex` for me). Then it converted to pdf without any further problems.